# JUnit 5 Surefire Maven: how to run tests for a dynamic web module project?

Tags: java, maven, junit

The "mvn test" compiles my test case, but it does not run it:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ test-server ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to my-server\backend\target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1:test (default-test) @ my-server ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
```

pom.xml properties:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <junit.jupiter.version>5.0.0</junit.jupiter.version>
    <junit.vintage.version>${junit.version}.0</junit.vintage.version>
    <junit.jupiter.version>5.0.0</junit.jupiter.version>
    <junit.platform.version>1.0.0</junit.platform.version>      
</properties>
```

Build settings:

```
<build>
    <finalName>my-server</finalName>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test</testSourceDirectory>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.vintage.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The test class is in the testSourceDirectory directory, its name begins with "Test", and it has the @Test annotation.

I suspect that the tests are not executed because the packaging is "war" instead of "jar". But I cannot change that - there is a single "packaging" setting for the whole project, and it must be "war" because it is really a web app.

So how do run my tests, and keep the "war" packaging at the same time?

**UPDATE** After adding the suggessted surefire provider, the test fails. surefire-reports/*.dump file shows this traceback:

```
# Created on 2017-12-17T10:58:50.171
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.maven.surefire.report.RunListener.testSetStarting(Lorg/apache/maven/surefire/report/ReportEntry;)V
    at org.junit.platform.surefire.provider.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeSingleClass(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.surefire.provider.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.surefire.provider.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:373)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:334)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:119)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:407)
```

Comment: First keep the conventions and don't change the directory structure by `<testSourceDirectory>src/test</testSourceDirectory>`..The test have to reside in `src/test/java`...instead...furthermore add a dependency to the maven-surefire-plugin (junit-platform-surefire-provider) see here: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/r5.0.2/junit5-maven-consumer/pom.xml

Comment: After adding the suggested plugin, I get a "NoSuchMethodError".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
JUnit 5 will works fine with following combination of dependencies and plugin version, both in JDK 8/11. 

Dependency
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

Build
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.0</version>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the signature of `org.apache.maven.surefire.report.RunListener.testSetStarting` [was changed](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/commit/4e993a05460ef72e17a39a6e9edf9e0ef402859f#diff-41f1fc804f4bdf4f54c954a5cd813c65) in 2.21.0.
junit-platform-surefire-provider depends on surefire-api.2.19.1, so it calls `testSetStarting` with an instance of `ReportEntry` where the method now accepts `TestSetReportEntry`.

The dependency is [upgraded to 2.21.0](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/commit/1b0acb9980bf3109319fc761c1bd2a33cfefe08b) so we'll just have to wait for the next release of junit 5.

I have built current master branch of junit,and can confirm that junit-platform-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT and juniper-5.2.0-SNAPSHOT works as expected.